# Java double to long conversion error mystery

Tags: java

Could someone please explain something to me.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    long a = 0;
    long b = 0;
    Random r = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        double d = r.nextDouble()*(r.nextBoolean() ? 1.0 : -1.0);

        a += d*100;
        b += (long)(100*d);
        //System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + d);

    }

    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    }
```

Why is a != b at the end of this loop. Is it a glitch in the matrix? If I remove the random signing of "d", then a == b. Why?

Comment: it seems a "rounding issue" , notable when you log the sums after each iteration... the first mismatch comes up with the first negative number...

Comment: with `d = -0.5078606970338732`, `a` is reduced by `51` (`a += d*100`), while `b` is reduced by `50` (`b += (long)(100*d)`) ...conclusion: `long` and `double` use different "rounding rules" on negative numbers ... proof: ...somewhere [in the specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17 : "...If the promoted type is int or long, then integer arithmetic is performed.

If the promoted type is float or double, then floating-point arithmetic is performed...." ;) good job, all! nice question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is what is rounded.

Your assignments:

```
a += d*100
b += (long)(100*d);
```

Will be executed as:

```
a = (long)(a + d * 100);
b = b + (long)(100 * d);
```

After one loop a and b can be different when a and b are positive while d is negative or vice versa. When adding d*100 to a, you are adding exact value (for example -1.1) while in case of b, it will be rounded first to -1.
Let's take an example. At the start of the loop we will have those values:

```
a = b = 1024
d = -0.178
```

the end result of single run will be:

```
a = (long)(1024-17.8) = (long)(1006.2) = 1006
b = 1024-(long)17.8 = 1024-17 = 1007
```

Comment: On the other hand I would never have guessed that that a|b would be converted into floating numbers if the right hand side are floating numbers. I think that's pretty unintuative, but I guessit's in the specification somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Java Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2) `+=` is specified like this:

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

That means that your two statements

```
  a += d*100;
  b += (long)(100*d);
```

are basically equivalent to

```
  a = (long) (a + d*100);
  b = (long) (b + (long)(100*d));
```

In the case of `a` the addition is between a `long` value and a `double` value, so the whole calculation will be done in the `double` realm.

In the case of `b` both parts of the addition are `long` values, so the calculation will use `long` maths.

Due to the fact that `long` and `double` have different value ranges the results can differ.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense to me. It makes sense if we were to go out of bounds of our value range for our different primitives. But if we initiate a & b = 231 and d = -0.277959324777002, then a => 203 and b => 204  clearly the range isn't breached. But it gave me another idea that it could be a rounding error? Did not think rounding errors could lead to this phenomena though...

Comment: Consider `(long) (1 + (-0.1))` vs `1L + ((long) -0.1)`.